# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message when SECOND time switch to iframe

Tags: selenium, iframe, pytest, timeoutexception

I have below fixture to navigate different navigate bar, but it will only work in the first time, when click next navigate bar, it will post the selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: error.
[image]

```
@pytest.fixture()
def navigateToQueue(setup, request):
    queuename = request.param
    WebDriverWait(setup, 20).until(
        EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, 
"//iframe[@title='Issuance']")))
    setup.find_element_by_xpath("//mat-icon[contains(text(),'menu')]").click()
setup.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[contains(text(),'{queuename}')]").click()
```

Comment: What are you doing here? Opening several tabs and trying to switch into iframe on each one of them?

Comment: Click the navigate bar icon(there are some menus under this icon)> navigate to each menu one by one

Comment: We are missing basic debugging details here. Can you share a link to the page you working on?

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the navigate bars